# Данные в FormData не видны в консоли

Tags: javascript

Вопрос из любопытства, почему данные в экземпляре `FormData` не видны при выводе в консоль, но при этом они видны во вкладке `Network`?
Вывод в консоль делал непосредственно перед отправкой, объект один и тот же.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// выдержки из кода компонента Vue

const formData = new FormData();
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
  formData.append(key, this.data[key]);
})
console.log(formData)

//метод отправляющий post-запрос на сервер.
this.$API.post(path, formData, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}).then()...

//под капотом используется axios
//.. выдержка из конструктора
post(path, payload, headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) {
  return this.service.request({
    headers,
    method: 'POST',
    url: path,
    responseType: 'json',
    data: payload,
  });
}
```

Comment: добавь немного кода, как ты отправлял и лог делал

Comment: @Grundy, сделал

Comment: Не видно потому что на момент просмотра данный объект уже пустой (в логе ссылка)

Comment: @JavaJunior, я тоже так думал и пробовал исключить какие либо действия, после вывода - результат тот же. В комментариях к первому ответу @eustatos, сказал что `данные полей формы - приватные переменные объекта FormData`- и это очень похоже на правду

Comment: @Дмытрык, судя по всему такая реализация в браузере. [Вот тут несколько вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17066875/2881286) обычно с помощью цикла советуют, но есть и интересный ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как [FormData](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata) является интерфейсом, предоставляемым браузером, внутренняя организация может зависеть от конкретных браузеров.

В дополнение к этому, вывод `console.log`, так же не специфицирован, что еще добавляет возможности различного вывода в различных браузерах.

Что можно увидеть в консоли chrome?

1. прототип установлен в FormData
2. в прототипе присутствуют все методы описанные в спецификации.

остальной вывод производится на усмотрение конкретного браузера.

Если посмотреть в спецификации, у каждого объекта FormData есть *ассоциированный* список со значениями.

Так как он *ассоциированный*, то может не являться *частью объекта*, следовательно текущий вывод вполне оправдан.

Answer (score 3):

Для вывода содержимого у FormData есть [методы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

```js
const form = document.forms['example-form'];


const exampleInput = document.querySelector('[name="example"]');

exampleInput.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);

function changeHandler() {
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  for (key of formData.keys()) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${formData.get(key)}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="example-form">
  <input name="example">
</form>
```

Comment: держите +). Но я не спрашивал "как получить данные?", я спросил "почему их не видно"?

Comment: Данные полей формы - приватные переменные объекта FormData. Публичные у него только методы.